# CustomMapView which can place markers based on the LatLng

Tags: android, geolocation, android-custom-view, android-mapview

Trying custom map view that can place views(users) according to their LatLng. The purpose is to show the representation where I have myself in the center and I can see the other users on my custom map view according to their current positions. I don't have the option to use google maps. I have tried to search out something similar like https://github.com/onlylemi/MapView but they are not using LatLng to place things.

Here is visual of desired output.

[image]